# Solve $g(g(x))=f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If $f(x)$ is a continuous and monotonically increasing function on an interval $(0,∞)$ and $f(x)>0$ for every $x>0$, then does there always exist a continuous and monotonically increasing function $g(x)$ on $(0,∞)$ so that for every $x\in (0,∞),g(x)\in (0,∞)$ and $g(g(x))=f(x)$?

If $f(x)=c~x^k~(c>0,k>0),$and $g(x)=r~x^{\sqrt{k}},$where $c=r^{\sqrt{k}+1},$then $g(g(x))=f(x)~(x>0).$

But how to solve it in general conditions?Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question needs to be refined, because $g(x)$ might not be in $(a,b)$ and hence $g(g(x))$ is undefined.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17614/solving-ffxgx

Comment: @Samuel Thanks for the link.

Comment: These functions must all satisfy $f\circ g=g\circ f$, so I raise doubt.

Comment: @Nick Kidman, although two randomly chosen functions won’t commute, a single (well-)chosen function may have lots of things that commute with it. It’s a somewhat subtle question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDDDITTT: the answer is YES. This is Theorem 11.2.2 on pages 424-423 of the KCG book mentioned below. I think I will put the jpeg at the end so that my text is readable.

A preliminary answer. The book you want is *Iterative Functional Equations* by [Kuczma, Choczewski, and Ger](http://www.cambridge.org/us/knowledge/isbn/item1120001/?site_locale=en_US). I got a used copy at a very reasonable price.

I put several items about the same problem for real analytic functions at [BAKER](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/other.html). The person who initiated this was Helmuth Kneser, father of Martin Kneser. He showed that there was a real analytic solution solving $g(g(x)) = e^x$ on the entire real line, meaning that it extends to a holomorphic function on an open set surrounding the real axis. Note that the question of commutation is exactly right: Baker re-worded the problem into one of commuting functions and formal power series. For the most difficult case an elaborate procedure was given by Ecalle in about 1973, see [QUESTION](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/formal-power-series-convergence) and my own [ANSWER](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/formal-power-series-convergence/46765#46765).

The main obstruction in the continuous case is that you cannot have fixed points of the target function with negative slope. However, you have said monotonic increasing. In case you have something like $x+ \sin x$ I think there is material in the KCG book for solving on each interval between fixpoints, but i will need to check that. If your function has no fixpoints or, say, only one, I think you can do it. But there may be no simple recipe or formula, just an existence result.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: what about the polygonal function $f(x)=4x$ if $x\le1$, $f(x)x+3

Comment: @Lubin, it can be done, because the rules in the original question say that the positive reals are mapped to the postive reals.

Comment: Please tell me you didn't just mark the spot there in the book.

Comment: @NickKidman, I did, but I buy these 2B leads for mechanical pencil, Pentel Hi-Polymer, which erase quite well. Also my copy is kind of smelly, if you store books in boxes for years they get moist, that is part of why it was cheap... If they want my mechanical pencil, they can come pry it out of my cold dead hand! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_my_cold,_dead_hands

Comment: $$\begin{array}{l}\text{Friar Barnardine. Thou hast committed-}\cr
\text{Barabas. Book defacing? But that}\cr
 \text{Was in another country, and besides}\cr
\text{The wench is dead.}\end{array}$$

Comment: A wonderful construction, @Will Jagy, which I had to try out on my polygonal function to see what made it work. The moral of the story is really interesting: it shows how extremely nonunique the $g$ is, and it shows as well that the centralizer of a given $f$ in the group of increasing self-homeomorphisms of the unit disk is extremely large.

Comment: @Lubin, glad you liked it. Given your moral, have you seen this from 2009 on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3332/two-commuting-mappings-in-the-disk   which convinced me that I had no idea what commuting functions actually meant.